Unable to Decrypt WhatsApp Flows Server Response
I am working on decrypting WhatsApp flow data using AES-GCM encryption in C#, but I’m encountering an issue when attempting to decrypt the flow data. Below is my Decryptor class, which handles both decryption of the AES key and flow data:
public class Decryptor
{
    public static DecryptedRequest DecryptRequest(EncryptedRequest body, string privatePem, string passphrase)
    {
        Log.Information("Decrypting request with body: {Bodyinitial_vector}", body.initial_vector);

        byte[] encryptedAesKey = Convert.FromBase64String(body?.encrypted_aes_key);
        byte[] encryptedFlowData = Convert.FromBase64String(body?.encrypted_flow_data);
        byte[] initialVector = Convert.FromBase64String(body?.initial_vector);

        byte[] decryptedAesKey;
        try
        {
            // Decrypt AES key using private key
            using (var rsa = CreateRsaPrivateKey(privatePem, passphrase))
            {
                decryptedAesKey = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedAesKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
                Log.Information("Decrypted AES Key: {decryptedAesKey}", decryptedAesKey);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FlowEndpointException(421, "Failed to decrypt the request. Please verify your private key.");
        }

        const int TAG_LENGTH = 16;
        byte[] flowDataBuffer = encryptedFlowData;
        byte[] initialVectorBuffer = initialVector;
        byte[] encryptedFlowDataBody = flowDataBuffer[..^TAG_LENGTH];
        byte[] encryptedFlowDataTag = flowDataBuffer[^TAG_LENGTH..];

        byte[] decryptedData;
        try
        {
            using (var aesGcm = new AesGcm(decryptedAesKey))
            {
                decryptedData = new byte[encryptedFlowDataBody.Length];
                aesGcm.Decrypt(initialVectorBuffer, encryptedFlowDataBody, decryptedData, encryptedFlowDataTag);
            }
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Decryption failed: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
            throw new FlowEndpointException(400, "Failed to decrypt the request.");
        }

        string decryptedJSONString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
        return new DecryptedRequest
        {
            DecryptedBody = decryptedJSONString,
            AesKeyBuffer = decryptedAesKey,
            InitialVectorBuffer = initialVectorBuffer
        };
    }
}

The decryption fails at the following point:
using (var aesGcm = new AesGcm(decryptedAesKey))
{
    decryptedData = new byte[encryptedFlowDataBody.Length];
    aesGcm.Decrypt(initialVectorBuffer, encryptedFlowDataBody, decryptedData, encryptedFlowDataTag);
}

The error message I get is:

System.ArgumentException: The specified nonce is not a valid size for this algorithm. (Parameter 'nonce')

This error suggests that the initialVector (nonce) being passed to the AES-GCM decryption is of an invalid size. However, I’ve confirmed that the initialVector is being correctly base64-decoded and passed as expected.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with AES-GCM decryption in C#? What could be the cause of the invalid nonce size, and how can I resolve it?
I tried decrypting this
{
    "encrypted_flow_data": "33oaKOMa2tsRCuh7g6JNsFzVB5icbm4dLq3sgrRXImxChcGOKWaTEZycsv/Tgg/jB/7cxQWH9D8HvJFkCc78X/avxOtEj0KbF+TuFKG28xO/HMR3A4rpzSyD37UAJy3eSmQ5CHZV7NOOMteJQNAOZQ3YEpcG/BcH8mo2iOQa2EA/8g==",
    "encrypted_aes_key": "NQBgEO5GMMXVHsRx0oDb+0MeTYPnHDZM2yJBG0CeaJ2VqN9ennPnLKknbVgpfRm7GfGSxsPHvO9sZeNs/SXlmYIoasDXw3pgKVjhPq3BOk93Fkfjs8bwBhDP763RCgO5IsOSgCqvNeGxeXxyM2BLr8rUAwoE74FYRLa6dxg5RGEUpGJjKLU8VZmBDbXanhPmy6+iVcLEE79rZLsA0+kU7IZ44eeR7PpvqiDCcrnjME/uCF24+3g+iVjsgcL5lA5DdhUQnfPnkjLTiC+x/NPp7ev3e7nP+PzTLQOxnnihjggRfYHUzklp9laVLAQoSQh7vvyKJUPyCv9BRhEmR7BJVQ==",
    "initial_vector": "Vs37z73b5OiBJ5hMV0kyUQ=="
}

and this is what am expecting at least
Decrypted Request:
{
    "data": {
        "farmer_select": "1"
    },
    "flow_token": "TEST",
    "screen": "DEMO_SCREEN",
    "action": "data_exchange",
    "version": "3.0"
}


From the AesGcm documentation: ...The nonce sizes supported by this instance: 12 bytes (96 bits)... Your nonce Vs37z73b5OiBJ5hMV0kyUQ== is 16 bytes in size after Base64 decoding, which makes the error message plausible.

12 bytes is the recommended nonce length for GCM, but it can also handle 16 bytes. However, the native C# class does not seem to support 16 bytes, so you need a different implementation (e.g. BouncyCastle).

Regarding your test data: This data is worthless as long as you only post the encrypted AES key. So add the decrypted AES key. If the data is sensitive, post new, non-critical sample data.
